# SSIS read the data from table and insert 2 rows in another table

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a requirement to read the data rows from one source table and insert different rows in another table

I have tried reading the rows from the table and inserting is working fine using data flow in SSIS

But based on the source rows(split source and insert into 2 rows in destination) based on Common ID

i.e Source System ID and Source System Key in one row and targetSystemID and Target system key in another row with same commonID,RefID

Example:

Source table columns & rows

```
RefID      SourceSystemID     SourceKey     TargetSystemID   TargetKey     CommonID   KeyDate
3           1                 9BFG06E8AD      2              001351913001  12345      20-02-2010 
4           1                 8KIJ67ASG9      2              002352014005  45678      20-02-2010
```

Required destination column rows

```
DataID(AutoIncrement)    RefID      SystemID          SystemKey      CommonID    DateCreated(using getdate())
1                        3          1                 9BFG06E8AD     12345       getdate()
2                        3          2                 001351913001   12345       getdate()
3                        4          1                 8KIJ67ASG9     45678       getdate()
4                        4          2                 002352014005   45678       getdate()
```

Can anyone assist please?

Comment: I would suggest using a column name of LoadTimeStamp vs DateCreated to avoid confusion down the road. This record was "not created" when you loaded it. It already existed somewhere else.

Comment: @Dale K :sql server

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` in SSIS.

There are two ways to use `UNION ALL` in SSIS

**1. Using SQL Query within SSIS**

Use this query as a source

```
SELECT Row_Number() over(order by RefId) AS DataID,*
FROM(
     SELECT RefID, SourceSystemID As SystemId, SourceKey, CommonID, GetDate() as CreatedDate
     FROM sample

     Union All

     SELECT RefID, TargetSystemID, TargetKey, CommonID, GetDate() as CreatedDate
     FROM sample
 ) AS T
 Order by RefId,SystemId
 ;
```

**2. Using SSIS Package Object**

Create two different OLE-DB Sources inside the `Dataflow Task`

like this (Though, Its sources are different but Instead of Excel & CSV, put two `OLE-DB Source`) and select only required columns in source one and two.

[image]

Please refer [this link](http://www.excoded.com/learn/ssis/ssis_unionall.php) to use `Union-All` in SSIS

EDITED: Check this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=029578dc24218b95a11f4deb57d8f9ed) to match your answer!

Comment: thanks Its working but the output is generating as 1st row,2nd ,3rd and 4th but how to get the exact output as I mentioned in the above?

Comment: @sivaramanvasu: check my edited fiddle link! Let me know what you are missing in it!